# how i can add more required * fields in checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i have installed word press + woo commerce, my site is running in Arabic language.

my check out page is contain these fields (first name - last name - E-mail - phone)

what i want: 
i hope to edit my checkout page by adding an extra fields like (Company name - position) how to do this

i hope if you explain me i didn't have any experience in PHP, CSS just i will apply your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If you at least know how to open your "functions.php" file, the following should work if you simply add it at the bottom of your functions.php file of your (child-)theme:

```
// Hook in

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_add_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_add_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['Company'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Company', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Company Name', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );


    $fields['billing']['Position'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Position', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Position', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );


     return $fields;
}
```

This should add the fields to the checkout page and have them be required. Then if you want to also add that information to the emails:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_custom_order_meta_keys');

function my_custom_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
     $keys[] = 'Company'; // This will look for a custom field called 'Company' and add it to emails
     $keys[] = 'Position';
     return $keys;
}
```

Snippets used from [this woocommerce doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

**PLEASE NOTE**

Adding this directly to your functions.php file of your theme and then updating your theme removes it - creating a child theme is best practice.
I know this whole answer might not help you, but it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a plugin to acheive this. there are several plugins on repository https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=custom+field+checkout.

So from here you can test some of these and choose your favorite. For example this one is easy to use https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-checkout-field/